# generate a inventory item coding in excel

Tags: excel, auto-generate

Can you support me in the following I need to create coding for inventory items

I built the structure ( 4 letters, and 4 digits)
(Warehouse Type, Warehouse Group, Family, Sub-Family) after that add a sequence 4 numbers
if the item in Warehouse Type ( A ), Warehouse Group (B ), Family(C), Sub-Family(D),

I need to generate a code ABCD0001, the following item if it from the same warehouse, group,family, and sub-family take generate code (ABCD0002),

BUT if the item has any different thing in structure starting from 0001

like if the item:
Warehouse Type ( B ), Warehouse Group (B ), Family(C), Sub-Family(D)
the code should be BBCD0001

what should I do to achieve this, I have almost 1200 items and I need to add a code for all of them

[image: code structure sample]

[image: Item as I want to be (generate a code column with sequence numbers if the item in the same warehouse and family and sub-family)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 4 lookup tables (for sample I have made two for Warehouse Type & Group seen on the left). Then apply the mapping you wish to have for each Type, Group, Etc.

In your raw data (on the right) create two helper columns: one to create your warehouse string and another to count the instances of those strings i.e. your sequence number

The formulas are below. Add them to first row of raw data and drag down to create the full list of unique keys

[image]

- `I2 = VLOOKUP(G2,$A$1:$B$6,2,0) & VLOOKUP(H2,$D$1:$E$6,2,0)`
- `J2 = I2 & TEXT(COUNTIF(I$2:I2,I2),"0000")`

---

*In cell `I2` you will need to combine 4 VLOOKUPS so just copy the method shown here. One for Type, Group, Family, & Sub-Family.*

Comment: Thank you i will check it but can you upload this excel file to me, if possible please

Comment: I cannot. Everything you neeed to recreate is right in the screen shot